# Arch Linux Installation: System freezes on boot

Tags: arch-linux, boot, system-installation

I have an old HP notebook (specs linked below) that I would like to install Linux on. On my main machine, I'm using Manjaro, and have grown to love the AUR and Arch environment. I'd really like to do the same on this computer, but both Manjaro and a vanilla Arch iso freeze up while booting the installer. Manjaro does so at the splash screen; Arch hangs immediately after `Reached target Login Prompts`. I'm guessing it's at the same spot. I've tried return, ctrl+alt+f*, alt+f*, every other key combo I can think might help, but nothing. I don't believe it's waiting for a response, as the formerly blinking cursor freezes as well.

Any advice?

Laptop specs: https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-14-cf0000-laptop-pc/20395769/document/c06254889

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this particular laptop doesn't like the latest kernel. Trying an old one fixed the issue.